# Seeking special abilities standard hit chance

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So, I was checking this question, [Do 'Seeking' ranged weapons work against nonconcealment miss chances? (3.5)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31008/do-seeking-ranged-weapons-work-against-nonconcealment-miss-chances-3-5) and I noticed that it stated in a comment that "Seeking weapons ignore normal miss chance because they always strike at their target" Looking for some clarification on this. Does that mean if I shoot a crossbow at an enemy who is in the open, or say, in Melee with an ally, that it is guaranteed to hit? Ergo, I don't even need to roll for attack? Or is the seeking special ability only meaningful against oponents who are using stealth or abilities to get bonuses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Miss" is a very specific thing that happens with concealment, blur, mirror image, among other things.

> Make the attack normally—if the attacker hits, the defender must make a miss chance d% roll to avoid being struck.

Clearly you need to make the attack roll as normal. You also need to overcome their AC. AFTER that, they get another chance to avoid the attack (the miss). The Seeking special weapon ability negates that extra chance, it doesn't affect the normal attack roll.

Comment: I'll repeat a comment I made on the linked question: The miss chance from Blink is still just a miss chance, and thus entirely negated by a Seeking weapon.

Comment: Do you mean *miss **chance*** in that first line?

Comment: No, but you could replace one with the other and have exactly the same meaning. I was clarifying that a "miss" is not the same thing as "failing to beat your AC".